# Magento - Assign option to multiselect attribute programmatically

Tags: php, magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

I have a custom attribute which is multi select type and I want to assign the value for it programatically but it doesn't work like "text field" attribute.

At the moment, I use the `product.update` in Magento's SOAP API to update the additional attribute.

I've tried and searched and tried but unluckily they didn't seem to work. I think this should work normally by default and we need some hack?

Is there any official document from magento about these kind of work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to write a setup script to add value to the multiselect attribute. Considering your attribute is color and you are trying to add value 'Red','Green','Blue' to the attribute, then you add like this

```
$oInstaller = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$iAttribId = $oInstaller->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'color');
$oInstaller->addAttributeOption(array(
        'attribute_id' => $iAttribId, 
        'value' => array(
            array(
                0 => 'Red',
                1 => 'Blue',
                2=> 'Green'
            )
        ),
    ));
```

Hope this works.

Comment: The problem is attribute options are created and I want to assign them to current product.

Comment: Did you mean that you have created a multiselect attribute with some values and trying to update a particular product with some values of the same attribute pro grammatically and not through the usual Magento Admin->Manage Products update?